# Cross join time series dataset applying asof criteria on time while limiting number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, join, time-series

I have a unique requirement around time-series analysis. Below I have presented my requirements along with a simple working solution. I have also worked out sample example to help understand my requirements.

I am seeking help with regards to making this code efficient in terms of **(a) reducing time & space complexity, (b) reducing lines of code if any of these can be achieved by using in-built functions in Pandas or other python libraries.**

Consider following time-series data for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: '09:13:46.867',1: '10:06:26.452', 2: '12:34:23.569', 3: '11:24:23.533', 4: '18:55:23.903', 5: '14:51:08.756'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC'}, 'Volume': {0: 100, 1: 300, 2: 600, 3: 1500, 4: 200}, 'Price': {0: 10.05, 1: 10.10, 2: 10.40, 3:10.50, 4: 10.45}, 'time': {0: '08:00:00.242', 1: '09:00:10.534', 2: '10:08:36.658', 3: '11:45:43.654', 4: '12:34:23.563'}})

print df1
print df2

         Date       EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11  09:13:46.867  08:00:00.241   ABC
1  2016-10-11  10:06:26.452  08:00:00.243   ABC
2  2016-10-11  12:34:23.569  12:34:23.563   ABC
3  2016-10-11  11:24:23.533  08:14:05.908   ABC
4  2016-10-11  18:55:23.903  18:54:50.100   ABC
5  2016-10-11  14:51:08.756  10:08:36.657   XYZ

         Date   Price Stock  Volume          time
0  2016-10-11   10.05   ABC     100  08:00:00.242
1  2016-10-11   10.10   ABC     300  09:00:10.534
2  2016-10-11   10.40   ABC     600  10:08:36.658
3  2016-10-11   10.50   ABC    1500  11:45:43.654
4  2016-10-11   10.45   ABC     200  12:34:23.563
```

I am looking to write following two functions in python in most efficient manner which takes following inputs:

```
def do_asof(df1, df2, left_time='StartTime', right_time='time', left_on=['Date','Stock'], right_on=['Date','Stock'], uptoCols=2)
def do_onafter(df1, df2, left_time='StartTime', right_time='time', left_on=['Date','Stock'], right_on=['Date','Stock'], uptoCols=2)
```

The first function `do_asof` does following:
    1. Performs an exact match between `df1` and `df2` on `left_on` and `right_on` columns. In this case an inner join on `'Date'` and `'Stock'` columns as follows: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['Date','Stock'])`
    2. Now in `df3`
        (a)  Get rid of all the rows where `'time' > 'StartTime'`. Do something like `df3 = df3.loc[df3['time'] <= df3['StartTime']]`
        (b)  Limit maximum of `uptoCols = 2` entries for each row in original `df1`. Do something like `df3 = df3.sort_values(['time'], ascending =[True]).groupby(['Date','Stock','StartTime','EndTime']).tail(2)`
        (c)  Outer Join to original df1 as follows to get the desired output `df4 = df1.merge(df3, on =['Date','Stock','StartTime','EndTime'],how = 'outer')`

```
print df4

         Date       EndTime     StartTime Stock  Price  Volume          Time
0  2016-10-11  09:13:46.867  08:00:00.241   ABC    NaN     NaN           NaN
1  2016-10-11  10:06:26.452  08:00:00.243   ABC  10.05     100  08:00:00.242
2  2016-10-11  12:34:23.569  12:34:23.563   ABC  10.50    1500  11:45:43.654
3  2016-10-11  12:34:23.569  12:34:23.563   ABC  10.45     200  12:34:23.563
4  2016-10-11  11:24:23.533  08:14.05.908   ABC  10.05     100  08:00:00.242
5  2016-10-11  18:55:23.903  18:54:50.100   ABC  10.50    1500  11:45:43.654
6  2016-10-11  18:55:23.903  18:54:50.100   ABC  10.45     200  12:34:23.563
7  2016-10-11  14:51:08.756  10:08:36.657   XYZ    NaN     NaN           NaN
```

The second function `do_onafter` does following:
    1. Performs a similar exact match between `df1` and `df2` on `left_on` and `right_on` columns. In this case an inner join on `'Date'` and `'Stock'` columns as follows: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['Date','Stock'])`
    2. Now in `df3`
        (a)  Get rid of all the rows where `'time' < 'StartTime'`. Do something like `df3 = df3.loc[df3['time'] >= df3['StartTime']]`
        (b)  Limit maximum of `uptoCols = 2` entries for each row in original `df1`. Do something like `df3 = df3.sort_values(['time'], ascending =[True]).groupby(['Date','Stock','StartTime','EndTime']).head(2)`
        (c)  Outer Join to original df1 as follows to get the desired output `df4 = df1.merge(df3, on =['Date','Stock','StartTime','EndTime'],how = 'outer')`

```
print df4

         Date       EndTime     StartTime Stock  Price  Volume          Time
0  2016-10-11  09:13:46.867  08:00:00.241   ABC  10.05     100  08:00:00.242
1  2016-10-11  09:13:46.867  08:00:00.241   ABC  10.10     300  09:00:10.534
2  2016-10-11  10:06:26.452  08:00:00.243   ABC  10.10     300  09:00:10.534
3  2016-10-11  10:06:26.452  08:00:00.243   ABC  10.40     600  10:08:36.658
4  2016-10-11  12:34:23.569  12:34:23.563   ABC  10.45     200  12:34:23.563
5  2016-10-11  11:24:23.533  08:14.05.908   ABC  10.10     300  09:00:10.534
6  2016-10-11  11:24:23.533  08:14.05.908   ABC  10.40     600  10:08:36.658
7  2016-10-11  18:55:23.903  18:54:50.100   ABC    NaN     NaN           NaN
8  2016-10-11  14:51:08.756  10:08:36.657   XYZ    NaN     NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Since it sounds like code here works and you are looking for efficiency, consider posting on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Folks will give you in-depth advice there.

Comment: Thanks Parfait. Will do so.